Draw renderer-line only on roads
I was wondering if it's possible to make my line renderer to be drawn only on the road asset. The problem I'm having is that I bought this asset and the road is combined with street.
Is there any way to make the line to be drawn only on the road itself?

I did put layers and use navigation to bake, but I expected the line draw on top of the street part as well.

Is the road and sidewalk one shared material?

No they have separate materials
